# How exactly select statement works in channel?

Tags: go

> A select blocks until one of its cases can run, then it executes that case.

I was testing `select` case, and I got an unexpected result:

```
func main() {
    channel1 := make(chan string)
    channel2 := make(chan string)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            channel1 <- "I'll print every 100ms"
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 100)
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
            channel2 <- "I'll print every 1s"
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
        }
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        select {
        case message1 := <-channel1:
            fmt.Println(message1)
        case message2 := <-channel2:
            fmt.Println(message2)
        }
    }
}
```

Most of the time it printed `1s` and this is perfect with goroutines. But once it printed `1s` in between the `100ms`:

```
/*
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run . # WHY 1s IS EXCECUTED IN BETWEEN?
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 1s # HERE?
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
$ go run .
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
*/
```

As per the `select` statement, I expected it to result because it selected `100ms` first:

```
/*
# Either
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 1s
# Or
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 1s
# But not:
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 1s
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
I'll print every 100ms
*/
```

Or, am I misunderstanding `select` statement?

Comment: [super's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66963999/2541573) is as good as it gets. When both cases are ready, either one will be selected. Since the sleep statements in the first two goroutines occur after the sends, you cannot expect the receive from channel2 to occur before the receive from channel1. Besides, because you're using unbuffered channels and the total number of receives (5) doesn't match the total number of sends (10), you're leaking one to two goroutines by the time `main` terminates. Not a big deal in such a simple programme, but worth noting in general.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending on the channel before you sleep, so which one comes first depends on which of the goroutines are faster to start up and run.

If you have a select where multiple cases are ready, the order is random.

Comment: I acknowledge the order is random but it should block until select case finishes.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar If the order is random, why would you expect a certain order?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar: sure, but so what? One sender starts sending, the other sender starts sending, both sends are blocked, your select begins, your select picks either `1s` or `100ms` channel at random, you read one of the messages at random, you print it, and you go back and read again which immediately unblocks the other reader since all this happens within microseconds. So `1s` and `100ms` comes out in a random order.

Comment: @torek if this kind of operations happen then we really don't need to use select case. The select case should block until it finishes all.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar: feel free to write your own equivalent of channels that do that. I'm not sure how you intend to define "finishes all" though.

Comment: @torek I meant when select case selected `100ms` it should not go with `1ms` until it finishes. See the expected result in my question.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar That would not make any sense. The select statement doesn't know how many packets will be sent on each channel or how often. How would it know when it "finished" on the 100ms channel?

Comment: @super That's what the select statement we use, otherwise I don't think we need it. We could directly run the statement without select case.

Comment: @super Then, can you please explain why we need to use `select` statement exactly if the order is random as how you're stating?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Normally you don't care about the order. You just want to handle two or more channels at the same time. If you need things to happen in a certain order there a many different ways to do that. Channels without select, waitgroups, mutexes, ect.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar The primary use-case for channels is to provide communication between different goroutines. So it's a way to synchronize async code. When dealing with async code you can never be sure what order things will happen in.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar the order is only random *when multiple cases are ready at the same time*. In your code, the first time the `select` executes, *both* goroutines may have already sent on the channel; because you sleep *after* sending, the first time they execute, there's no difference between the two, they both send immediately, *then* they wait different amounts of time. The sends already happened. `select` is for cases where you don't know which channel will be ready first, and you want whichever one is ready first; therefore, if multiple are ready at once, you don't care which you get.